# socket.error: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket

Tags: python, macos, sockets

I'm using Python on Mac.

But the below code

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 443))
s.listen(2048)
```

encounters the problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attacker.py", line 5, in <module>
    s.listen(2048)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need `SOCK_STREAM` for a listening socket, not DGRAM.

Comment: Amazingly, nothing in the python socket docs for `listen` ---
*socket.listen([backlog])
Enable a server to accept connections. If backlog is specified, it must be at least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); it specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections. If not specified, a default reasonable value is chosen.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using a udp socket, SOCK_DGRAM, and udp does not listen for connections, it receives each message on its own
Use recvfrom to receive udp messages