# Python TCP socket on connect OSError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am trying to connect via TCP to a socket. I have a UDP and TCP socket created on the same host/port address and is created like this:

```py
self.udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

self.udp_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self.udp_socket.bind((gethostname(), self.port))

self.tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
self.tcp_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

self.t_lock = threading.Condition()

# UDP THREAD
self.listen_udp_thread = threading.Thread(
    name="Listen UDP", target=self.listen_udp
)
self.listen_udp_thread.daemon = True
self.listen_udp_thread.start()

# TCP THREAD
self.listen_tcp_thread = threading.Thread(
    name="Listen TCP", target=self.listen_tcp
)
self.listen_tcp_thread.daemon = True
self.listen_tcp_thread.start()
```

I'm listening on the TCP socket like this:

```py
def listen_tcp(self):

    """Start listening for TCP connections"""
    self.tcp_socket.bind((gethostname(), self.port))
    self.tcp_socket.listen()
    print("TCP socket is listening...")

    while True:
        # Listen for TCP data
        conn, addr = self.tcp_socket.accept()  # accept connections
        if conn:
            print(f"Connected to {addr}")

        while True:
            with self.t_lock:
                data = conn.recv(2048)
                if not data:
                    self.t_lock.notify()
                    break  # this will close the connection
                print("TCP:", data)
                conn.send(data)

        conn.close()  # closes once connection broken
```

And then I am sending data on the same TCP socket like this:

```py
def send_tcp(self, message, node_id, addr=None):

    """Wrapper function to send message and print to stdout"""

    if node_id is not None:
        addr = (gethostname(), self._id_to_port(node_id))

    with self.t_lock:
        self.print_out(message, addr)

        try:
            self.tcp_socket.connect(addr)
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print(
                f"> {bcolors.FAIL}Connection to {addr[0]}:{addr[1]} refused!{bcolors.ENDC}"
            )
        else:
            while True:
                self.tcp_socket.send(message.encode())
                response = self.tcp_socket.recv(2048)
                self.print_in("TCP RESPONSE: " + response, addr)
                if not response:
                    break

            self.tcp_socket.close()

        self.t_lock.notify()
```

However when I send a message over TCP (invoke `send_tcp()`) I get the error:
`OSError: [Errno 102] Operation not supported on socket`

the same `t_lock` is also used in the UDP listener/sender. I am able to recieve / send UDP pings between "nodes" (what the class is called in my case) fine.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325912/socket-error-errno-102-operation-not-supported-on-socket

Comment: @Scott I did see that one - I have triple checked that I am using self.tcp_socket which is defined using SOCK_STREAM. I have also just commented out the self.udp_socket and I get the same issue (so not an issue using same address/port). Could it be a problem with me both sending and receiving on the same socket?